# Spring Boot map single JSON to two entities

Tags: spring-boot

A single JSON is posting from Postman and having two entity names as employee and employee address. From that JSON, `empName` should be stored in first entity and `empAddress` should be stored in second entity.

How to do this in Spring Boot? I tried to write only Entities.

First Entity:

```
class Employee{
    private int emId;
    private String empName;
    //Getters;
    //Setter;
}
```

Second Entity:

```
class EmployeeAddress{
    private int emId;
    private String empAddress;
    //Getters;
    //Setter;
}
```

My JSON: the firt value in JSON need to be stored in first entity and second need to be stored in second entity. How to do this in Spring Boot from controller?

```
{
    "empName": "sam",
    "empAddress:"chennai"
}
```

Comment: you can map the JSON to a single holder object - like Request/Dto and then create the Domain objects out of the Request/Dto object.

Comment: Can u give one examples

Answer (score 0):

You need a DTO.

Something like this:

```
class Employee{
    private String empName;
    private String empAddress;
}
```

So, you can return this object as a Json

Comment: Thank you...can u explain it with by controller and how to map from dto to entity